# How can I manufacture pathological keys for a hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to trigger the hash randomization feature in Perl 5.8.2 and later.  To do this, I need a set of keys that would be pathological but for the randomization feature.  I tried using [`MJD's code`](http://perl.plover.com/badhash.pl), but that didn't work.  And, now that I look at it, I shouldn't be surprised.  It comes from 1997, and we have switched hashing functions since then.

Does anyone know of a set of pathological keys, or how to generate them?  I guess I should just go look at the hash function and reverse engineer a solution, but I am lazy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note:** this information is valid for perl between 5.8.2 and 5.17.x. Beginning with perl 5.18, perl uses a new hash algorithm, hash randomization occurs on every startup (instead of only when a pathological hash is detected), and `PERL_HASH_SEED` is interpreted differently. As perl now uses a 128-bit hash seed, the "pathological hash" condition should be almost impossible to trigger intentionally.

**Original answer:** If you force the hash seed to 0 by putting `PERL_HASH_SEED=0` in the environment before perl starts, the collection of keys `"\0"`, `"\0\0"`, `"\0\0\0"`, etc. will cause every key to land in hash bucket 0 with current perls.

Comment: hmm, `PERL_HASH_SEED` is what I am trying to test, but the `"\0" x $keynum` will probably do what I want.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick.  I can now reliable force a hash to be rehashed.